# How to add autogenerated files to the final jar of 'java-library' module?

Tags: gradle, annotations, kotlin

I have module in the managed by gradle project. Some classes are creating by annotation processing. But after all these autogenerated files doesn't come to the final jar. How to add them?

build.gradle of the module:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation libraries.kotlinStdLib
    implementation libraries.rxjava

    compile project(':generator:annotation')
    kapt project(":generator:processor")
    compileOnly project(":generator:processor")
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    main.java.srcDirs += "${buildDir.absolutePath}/tmp/kapt/main/kotlinGenerated/"
    debug.java.srcDirs += 'src/debug/kotlin'
    debug.java.srcDirs += "${buildDir.absolutePath}/tmp/kapt/debug/kotlinGenerated/"

    release.java.srcDirs += 'src/release/kotlin'
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
    androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/kotlin'
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath libraries.kotlinPlugin
        classpath libraries.kotlinStdLib
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Generted files are visible inside this package, tested by JUnit etc. Also these files are visible by Android Studio.

```
$ find . -type f | grep Fsm*
./build/classes/kotlin/main/com/example/FsmPaymentInteractorImpl.class
./build/classes/kotlin/main/com/example/FsmSettingsInteractorImpl.class
./build/tmp/kapt/main/kotlinGenerated/FsmPaymentInteractorImpl.kt/com/example/FsmPaymentInteractorImpl.kt
./build/tmp/kapt/main/kotlinGenerated/FsmSettingsInteractorImpl.kt/com/example/FsmSettingsInteractorImpl.kt
$
```

There is no files in the jar:

```
$ find . -name domain.jar | xargs tar tf | grep Fsm
$
```

Ideas?

**Update:**

I found unexpected behaviour: if I run `jar` task twice, desired files are adding to the jar. Why??

```
$ ./gradlew -q  :domain:jar ; find . -name Fsm* -type f
./domain/build/classes/kotlin/main/com/example/FsmPaymentInteractorImpl.class
./domain/build/classes/kotlin/main/com/example/FsmSettingsInteractorImpl.class
./domain/build/tmp/kapt/main/kotlinGenerated/FsmPaymentInteractorImpl.kt/com/example/FsmPaymentInteractorImpl.kt
./domain/build/tmp/kapt/main/kotlinGenerated/FsmSettingsInteractorImpl.kt/com/example/FsmSettingsInteractorImpl.kt

$ ./gradlew -q  :domain:jar ; find . -name Fsm* -type f
./domain/build/classes/kotlin/main/com/example/FsmPaymentInteractorImpl.class
./domain/build/classes/kotlin/main/com/example/FsmSettingsInteractorImpl.class
./domain/build/tmp/kapt/main/classFileStubs/com/example/FsmPaymentInteractorImpl.class
./domain/build/tmp/kapt/main/classFileStubs/com/example/FsmSettingsInteractorImpl.class
./domain/build/tmp/kapt/main/kotlinGenerated/FsmPaymentInteractorImpl.kt/com/example/FsmPaymentInteractorImpl.kt
./domain/build/tmp/kapt/main/kotlinGenerated/FsmSettingsInteractorImpl.kt/com/example/FsmSettingsInteractorImpl.kt

$ find . -name domain.jar | xargs tar tf | grep Fs
com/example/FsmPaymentInteractorImpl.class
com/example/FsmSettingsInteractorImpl.class
$
```

Comment: Which versions of Gradle and Kotlin plugin are you using?

Comment: By the way, you seem to use the old Kotlin annotation processing tool (you don't apply the plugin `kotlin-kapt`), which is deprecated. Please try to add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` to your build script and remove the `kapt { generateStubs = true }` block.